# UV mapping shading different on each part

Tags: texturing, uv, shaders, vertex-groups, vector-mapping

I was wondering if there is an easy fix for making the texture appear the same on the whole object, despite having multiple cuts in the UV map. It is imported from OnShape as object, that's the reason for this messy mesh.

All the parts are rotated the same direction but this did not help. I tried making it all squares with the add-on and cleaning up the mesh with merge by distance.

I could remodel but if anyone know how the texture can be displayed equal on all parts that would be nice!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi :). If the mesh is symmetrical, you could cut it in half, unwrap, and use Mirror Modifier to generate the other half

Comment: Otherwise, you'd need to perfectly overlay the UV islands (and flip some) which is waaay more complicated ;)

Comment: @JachymMichal It is symmetrical, didn't think about that.. thanks! But even on one side there are already some issues, with island that are rotated in similar directions.

yes flipping and cleaning up the mesh would be more complicated than remodel it heh, but thanks for the feedback!